# Converting contacts for UbuntuOne

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, thunderbird, contacts, couchdb

I run Ubuntu 11.10 with Thunderbird as main address book; I also have the `thunderbird-couchdb` package installed.

I know the U1 Contacts [service status](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status#Contacts) has not been working lately:

> Contacts
>
> 2011-11-29 Syncing of contacts is not working for some users due to server issues. On 2011-10-10 we released an update to all clients
>   to help ease the load on the server and improve reliability of
>   syncing. We're now working on finishing up adding additional server
>   hardware.

, but I would like to start making my local contact couchdb database (so my main address book would not be TB one anymore), so it could be synced when the service restarts in a stable manner (and I could access to it from anywhere).
Here is the screenshot of my address books in TB:
[image: screenshot]
In details I would like to:

- Understand if and where web address books (the ones with the globe icon) are stored in my fylesystem, so I can backup them;
- understand which web address book gets synced with U1 (surely it's the one named `Ubuntu One`, but I cannot get any useful property from TB)
- Copy (and not move) my TB contacts (the ones with the book icon) to the couchdb database that will get synced;
- Copy (and not move) my Google contacts to the couchdb database that will get synced;

Any step-by-step idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu One contacts integration in its current form is going away for P (12.04), and doesn't currently work at all well. I'd recommend removing it from the desktop completely until Q (12.10).

Comment: Is this feature approved for 12.10?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: "going away for P (12.04)/remove it until Q (12.10)": I was wondering if U1 Contacts integration is already planned to be improved and restored in time for Q, after Q or if this topic is still open.

Comment: It was originally planned to be released around P (so not in P). I haven't revised those plans, but they might've slipped a little, but not a lottle. So still Q, yes. If Ubuntu picks it up, which I have no reason to suppose they won't.

Answer (score 1):

Duane from support sent me this answer which I thought would be useful for people regarding this matter:

> HI,
>
> Currently Ubuntu One mobile contact sync is being completely redesigned.
>   Syncing contacts to your iphone/ipod will be available later this year. The
>   desktop syncing of contacts is a similar story. In its current form it does not
>   work well and is going away for Ubuntu 12.04. I would recommend not using it
>   until Ubuntu 12.10.

FYI: I've asked for permission to post this here.